# How to access my ViewController and Scene instants in a playground?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I have created a playground and added my Swift files into its *source* folder so I can access to class and instantiate them as I need, but I need to use playground more!
[image: xcode]
I have a typical problem with Sprites positioning in SpriteKit, and I need to test sprite positions and gestures touch point positions with the poayground, I have different anchor nodes for each group of Sprites in my game and each I am facing with three coordinate system

1. Gestures coordinate system that its origin is top left
2. SpriteKit coordinate system that relays at the center of screen
3. Isometric Map coordinate system that shows each sprite on a isometric map.

By adding a scale facility (using pinch gesture) as a grain salt, I have a very sophisticated geometric calculations, each conversion is very simple itself however conbing these affine transformations is total mess, I don’t like the codes I am writing.

I need some testing to see how one affine transformation affect the previous one and how should I convert coordinates between these three coordinate systems.

I used to use println and breakpoints to watch my variables but it wasn’t enough, I found playground very usefull so I guess there must be a way so I can watch my variables there or test my functions over the real data when I am testing my game.

## Question :

Is it possible to have gestures touch points in my playground? they are passing to my handle gestures functions and all test codes that suppose to write or transform these touch point must be written in handle gestures functions, the question is can I use them in my playground?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to make your classes public to use them in playground.
And it's possible to use touch in playground and interact with it.

Have a look to this.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

struct Pokemon {
    let id: UInt
    let name: String
}

class PokedexViewController: UITableViewController {
    let pokemons: [Pokemon] = [
        Pokemon(id: 1, name: "Bulbasaur"),
        Pokemon(id: 2, name: "Ivysaur"),
        Pokemon(id: 3, name: "Venusaur"),
        Pokemon(id: 4, name: "Charmander"),
        Pokemon(id: 5, name: "Charmeleon"),
        Pokemon(id: 6, name: "Charizard"),
        Pokemon(id: 7, name: "Squirtle"),
        Pokemon(id: 8, name: "Wartortle"),
        Pokemon(id: 9, name: "Blastoise")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 1
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pokemons.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "PokemonTableViewCell")

    let pokemon = pokemons[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = pokemon.name

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let pokemon = pokemons[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = PokemonViewController(frame: tableView.frame, pokemon: pokemon)

    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}

}

class PokemonViewController: UIViewController {
    private let pokemon: Pokemon

    init(frame: CGRect, pokemon: Pokemon) {
        self.pokemon = pokemon
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.title = self.pokemon.name
        self.view = UIView(frame: frame)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let rootViewController = PokedexViewController()
rootViewController.title = "Pokedex"

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:rootViewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController.view
```

Comment: It is better to put code directly into your answer, and it will sit there forever. Think of users who will read it years later when gist will be cleaned up or dead.

Comment: @AmadeuCavalcanteFilho Thanks